# How to make text responsive in custom html in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I am using wordpress with Gutenberg editor. So I made a custom html widget within I have this:

```
<div style=
"background:#72BF44;height:100px">
<span style="position: absolute;
color: #FFFFFF;
width: 592px;
height: 65px;
padding:10px;
margin:-5px

font-family: 'Poppins';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 16px;
line-height:2px;"> <p>Wij zijn een collectief van inwoners en ondernemers uit Den Haag</p> 
<p style="line-height:5px">en omstreken en bouwen aan een menswaardige samenleving en een</p>
<p>zelfredzame regio in harmonie met de natuur. Word jij een van ons?</p>
</span>
</div>
```

But how to make this now responsive?

Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
<div style=
"background:#72BF44;overflow-wrap: break-word;">
<span style="
color: #FFFFFF;
width: 592px;
height: 65px;
padding:10px;
margin:-5px

font-family: 'Poppins';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 16px;
line-height:0.7;
 overflow-wrap: break-word;"> <p>Wij zijn een collectief van inwoners en ondernemers uit Den Haag</p> 
<p style="line-height:5px">en omstreken en bouwen aan een menswaardige samenleving en een</p>
<p>zelfredzame regio in harmonie met de natuur. Word jij een van ons?</p>
</span>
</div>
```

But then on mobile looks like this:

[image]

Oke, I have it now like this:

```
<div style=
"background:#72BF44;overflow-wrap: break-word;">
<span style="
color: #FFFFFF;
width: 592px;
height: 65px;
padding:10px;
margin:0

font-family: 'Poppins';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 16px;
line-height:0.7;
 overflow-wrap: break-word;"> <p>Wij zijn een collectief van inwoners en ondernemers uit Den Haag</p> 
<p style="line-height:5px">en omstreken en bouwen aan een menswaardige samenleving en een</p>
<p>zelfredzame regio in harmonie met de natuur. Word jij een van ons?</p>
</span>
</div>
```

But still on mobile the middle sentence is a hustle.

Comment: Can you add `<style>` tag or only inline style?

Comment: Hello, before trying to reset line-height, do reset p vertical margins (defaut is 1em ) `p{margin:0;}` From there, you can , if needed, reset line-height padding and margins to the value that suits you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> check this out https://jsfiddle.net/7rpntbak/18/
> don't use pixels in line-height try it like this `line-height:1` or `line-height:0.8`